# Magento related items with custom options add to cart not working

Tags: php, magento, product

In magento when i tried to add related items to cart it doesn't work. I have gone through some references and i found that it has problem only if it has custom options. Products without custom options work prefectly.

I hope it is common for all magento community editions. My Magento version is 1.5.0.1

I tried goole for this solution but no luck. I have also gone through the extensions but i couldn't find one. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Related products wont added in cart,because the customer has to choose proper option.For example,if size is custom option,value must be selected while adding to cart.That make sense right?

Comment: Yeah indeed. I want to rectify this problem like display the custom options under the related product names or add with a default admin selected option. I couldn't find a good way to do this. Please help. Thanks